# Consulta em SQL, consultar um numero limitado de registro

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou tendo um problema em relação ao limite de retorno de informações por consulta,

Por exemplo:

Eu possuo uma tabela chamada "Carros". Nesta tabela possui 2 campos "Modelo" e "Cor".

Como posso fazer uma consulta que me retorne 3 carros do modelo Gol e 2 carros do modelo Celta?.

Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que seja algo relacionado ao "LIMIT", porém não estou conseguindo fazer com 2 condições, que neste caso é limitar a consulta para 3 carros do modelo Gol e 2 carros do modelo Celta.

Nota: estou utilizando o Mysql.

Comment: Por exemplo, no MySQL você pode mesclar várias _queries_ usando `UNION` para obter um resultado só: `(SELECT modelo, cor FROM carros WHERE modelo="Gol" LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT modelo, cor FROM carros WHERE modelo="Celta" LIMIT 2)`. Seria interessante clicar em [edit] e acrescentar o tipo de BD que está usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na maioria dos casos o SQL não possui funções para isso. se estive usando o MySQL é certo que não é possível. Porem para resolver seu problema é possível adotar duas abordagens.

- Usar duas consultas diferentes no PHP
- Usar a função UNION do Mysql

No PHP basta criar duas consultas diferentes e executar. Exemplo:

```php
$return = array();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `modelo`, `cor` WHERE `modelo` = :modelo LIMIT :limit');
$stmt->execute( array( ':modelo' => 'Gol', ':limit' => 3 ) );
$list = $res->fetchAll();
foreach( $list as $record ) {
    $return[] = $record;
}

$stmt->execute( array( ':modelo' => 'Celta', ':limit' => 2 ) );
$list = $res->fetchAll();
foreach( $list as $record ) {
    $return[] = $record;
}

return $return;
```

No Mysql você pode recorrer ao UNION ficando assim seu PHP;

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
    ( SELECT `modelo`, `cor` WHERE `modelo` = :modelo1 LIMIT :limit1 )
    UNION
    ( SELECT `modelo`, `cor` WHERE `modelo` = :modelo2 LIMIT :limit2 )
');

$stmt->execute( array(
    ':modelo1' => 'Gol',
    ':limit1' => 3,
    ':modelo2' => 'Celta',
    ':limit2' => 2
) );
return $res->fetchAll();
```

Ambos os casos resolvem o problema, porem o deixa engessado para reaproveitar em outra situação futuramente. Sendo assim, você poderá recorrer as duas opções criando uma função que recebe o array com os parâmetros.

Para a primeira opção é criado um laço de repetição para executar uma consulta por posição do array passado para a função, ficando assim:

```php
function modelos ($parameters) {
    $return = array();

    foreach( $parameters as $parameter ) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `modelo`, `cor` WHERE `modelo` = :modelo LIMIT :limit');
        $stmt->execute( $parameter );
        $list = $res->fetchAll();

        foreach( $list as $record ) {
            $return[] = $record;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Para a segunda opção é criado um laço de repetição para concatenar mais consultas ao sql.

```php
function modelos ($parameters) {
    $sql = array();
    $newParameters = array();

    foreach( $parameters as $index => $parameter ) {
        $sql[] = '( SELECT `modelo`, `cor` WHERE `modelo` = :modelo' . $index . ' LIMIT :limit' . $index . ' )';
        $newParameters[':modelo' . $index] = $newParameters[':modelo'];
        $newParameters[':limit' . $index] = $newParameters[':limit'];
    }
    $sql = join(' UNION ', $sql);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($newParameters);
    return $res->fetchAll();
}
```

Para chamar os métodos:

```
$parameters = array (
    array( ':modelo' => 'Gol', ':limit' => 3 ),
    array( ':modelo' => 'Celta', ':limit' => 2 )
);
$modelos = modelos($parameters);
```

As duas funções podem afetar o desempenho do sistema dependendo da quantidade de consulta, mas para o problema apresentado são algumas soluções viáveis, e creio que a função de consultas diferentes no PHP é algo mais elegante.